# "Minimal factorisation" of a morphism

Tags: category-theory

Suppose I have a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ in some category. I want to ask for something like "the object that contains the minimum amount of information about $X$ needed to reproduce $Y$."

My guess is that the right way to do that is to ask for an object $A$ and morphisms $f_0\colon X\to A$, $f_1\colon A\to Y$, such that $X\xrightarrow{f_0}A\xrightarrow{f_1}Y = X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ and such that $A$ is universal, in that for any other object $B$ equipped with similar arrows there is a unique $h$ making this diagram commute:

[image]

Does this have a name? (Or is there another better way to talk about "the minimal factorisation of $f$"?)

Comment: Your concept is too general, so the solution to your universal problem is just $X\to Y = Y$ (ie $A=Y$, $f_0=f$, $f_1=\mathrm{id}$). What you can do is restrict either $A$ or $f_0$ or $f_1$ to be in certain class of objects/ morphisms ; and then the existence of such a factorisation depends on the category. For example, in a abelian category you can factor any morphism as a surjection, then an injection (through the image).

Comment: @vanxoo hmm, you're right. I knew something looked wrong about that diagram but couldn't figure out what it is. Maybe an epi-mono factorisation is what I need, then.

Comment: When you say you want "the object that contains the minimum amount of information about $X$ needed to reproduce $Y$," this actually never mentions the morphism $f$ and so its not clear why you introduce or use $f$. Could you elaborate a little more on why you want such an object?

There is the image of $f$, which maybe could be what you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)#:~:text=In%20category%20theory%2C%20a%20branch%20of%20mathematics%2C%20the,a%20generalization%20of%20the%20image%20of%20a%20function.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName thank you, that's really helpful. I meant something like the minimum information about $X$ needed to capture the way $Y$ depends on $X$ according to $f$. So in a Set-like category, if you know $a=f_0(x)$ you can forget $x$ and still reconstruct $y = f(x) = f_1(a)$. I think that basically *is* the image, except that I was thinking of it as a compressed version of $X$ instead of a subset of $Y$, so I didn't realise it. The definition there is basically what I wrote, except that I'd missed the condition that the morphism into $Y$ has to be monic.

Comment: In other words, I was thinking of it as a [coimage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coimage), but I'd missed the condition that $f_0$ has to be epic. I'm pretty sure a coimage is exactly what I want (and might be equal to the image in my case).

Answer (score 1):

This is a self-answer by the OP, summarising comments by @vanxoo, @IsAdisplayName and me.

My definition as written doesn't work, because we just end up with $A=X$, $f_0=f$ and $f_1 = \mathrm{id}_Y$.

However, what I probably want is the [coimage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coimage), which is the same as what I wrote, except that we impose the condition that $f_0$ has to be an epimorphism (as does the morphism $X\to B$).

In a sufficiently set-like category, if we have an epimorphism $X\twoheadrightarrow B$ we can think of it as a coarse-grained version of $X$. A factoring $X\twoheadrightarrow B\to Y = X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ gives us a coarse-graining of $X$ that still contains "enough information" to reconstruct $Y$ (as a function of $X$ according to $f$). The coimage is the terminal object in the category of such coarse-grainings, so it's essentially the coarsest coarse-graining that still contains the information needed to reconstruct $Y$.

Alternatively, we can ask for the dual concept, [image](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image), which has a similar definition except that we require $f_1$ to be a monomorphism instead, and we ask for the initial object instead of the terminal one. In Set and similar categories this gives us the image of $f$ as a function. The two concepts often coincide.